# A/B testing on IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, web-farm

I'm interested in setting up an A/B testing environment using IIS7 and a web farm.
But I faced problems with Microsoft's [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) (ARR) solution.

Could somebody share an idea on how to set it up using web farm toolkit?

I need to know how to define for IIS that all requests should follow rule e.g. 50% of traffic to host #1 and the rest to the second one.

Comment: You might want to explain what ARR is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

We are using hardware Barracuda and custom variables powered by Google Analytics.
using new interface of GA(beta) we made 2 segments in same time and received amazing visualization.